# Proportional height issues on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a very hard time to display UI properly on iPhone X, based on the screenshot, UI on iPhone X always get longer than normal iphones, is there any solutions on how to scale and display the ratio properly across all iPhone sizes? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: can you share your constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `imageView.width` proportional to `imageview.height` and not to `screen height`.
i think in this case height-to-width will be in 4:3 ratio
Also calulate youe imageview height based on screenheight with safe area excluded from it.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    if ((UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top)! > CGFloat(0.0)) {
       let safeArealength = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top + UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        height = ratio * (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - safeArealength)
        width = 0.75 * height //guess the ratio is 4:3
    }
}
```

here the `ratio` is the proportion between the `imageview` size and the `screensize`.

Comment: can I know how to set the width and height based on your suggestion?

Comment: is there any solution purely do on storyboard without coding?

Comment: @klkl what are the constraints on imageview now??

Comment: @klkl  no there's no way to solve this without code, my suggestion to create a variable for the height constraint and adjust it on ios11 devices

Comment: bro thanks for the help, seems I found an easier way which I set proportional height and width to safe area, then it gives me correct aspect ratio across all devices.

Comment: no need to do this     if ((UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top)! > CGFloat(0.0)) {
this will always give you values if on iphone x and for not on iphone x give you 0